# How to limit number of records in the Confluent Rest Proxy fetch records api

Tags: kafka-rest, confluent-rest-proxy

This is related GET API consumers/{consumergroup}/instances/{instanceId}/records

where we dont have any flag to control on the exact number of messages returned from this API.

Is there any other way to limit the number of records apart from timeout and max_bytes?

Tried with consumer.max.poll.records in the Rest-proxy configuration but this config is not applied on the rest API for GET API consumers/{consumergroup}/instances/{instanceId}/records